# JQuery: Ajax Cache - performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, caching

How does the Ajax cache in jQuery work and how does it compare to the old-fashioned way of  setting up Expiration with "file headers" as shown below (PHP)?

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

How does the Ajax cache invalidate and on what basis does that happen? I've never seen any detailed info on how it can be controller besides the below shown snippet:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below lines from jquery

cacheBoolean
Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
If set to false it will force the pages that you request to not be cached by the browser.

If the request exactly the same , jquery doesn't make the request again , the data will be completly availble in the browser cache. So that can improve the perormance.

Its not definetly a overhead on the browser as it already caches even you don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

When cache is false, jQuery adds a timestamp to the end of the request. This way, the URL changes and the cache doesn't exists.